# Is my understand of STUN and WebRTC correct?

Tags: c#, webrtc, stun

I'm trying to build a web-app/web-site that makes use of WebRTC to allow users to chat with each other.

I have managed to get it working when I initialize a new **RTCPeerConnection** without any parameters. I assume the browser automatically chooses some STUN server/s to use.

But this only works on my local network and not when I host the website on a public domain (eg, example.com).

This led me to try with my own STUN server...

So now I initialize the **RTCPeerConnection** with my server's IP address and I receive the STUN requests.

I am using the [RFC 5389](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389) specification to build the STUN server.

As I understand it, I should reply to a STUN request with the Ip Address and port that I received the request on.

So this is my **first question**, should I be responding to the different STUN requests with the other client's IP address or am I doing this correctly?

While building the STUN server I was using WireShark to look at the responses I generate and initially it would show an invalid Message Type for my UDP responses, but I've got it to show the STUN response fields, so I assume my responses are correct.
I also tested my STUN server on [this website](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) and it adds 2 items, one for TCP and one for UDP, but then after a while, it shows a **701** error code (STUN allocate request timed out.).
So i'm not 100% sure if my STUN server responds with the correct info.

I've also used stuntman to test my STUN server and it also shows success, but I'm not so sure that is very accurate.

The public google stun URL of **stun:stun.l.google.com:19302** also does not work, so I thought perhaps the STUN specification has changed.
My **second** question: Has the STUN spec changed or am I following the wrong one?

Then I have a **third** question:
I am also able to communicate between 2 different clients using web sockets, by using a pre-shared code or id.
I was wondering if I could initiate a WebRTC connection using this web socket connection instead of having to use or rely on STUN. I'm already sharing the offer and answer over the WebSocket connection, but those are now stuck waiting for ICE candidates.

And a **fourth** question is:
Is there any way to debug why my STUN responses are not working (I.E. creating ICE candidates) while setting up  RTCPeerConnection?

My STUN server is built with .Net using the UdpClient class if that's important.

Thanks in advance.

**Update: 20 Mar 2020**
I managed to get my app working when using the google STUN server as mentioned.
It looks like I was not adding the ice candidates on the client side.
But still not able to get it all working when using my own STUN server.
I've also tested by having my STUN server hosted on a public domain, so the requests have to go over the internet, but it still doesn't work.
My host receives ice candidates, but it does not receive the **null** candidate.

**Update: 21 Mar 2020**
So I figured out why it started working.
The **iceTransportPolicy** value in the RTCPeerConnection was set to **relay**. Removing this completely made things work, even on my public domain site.
But now requests to my own STUN server are being ignored.

When iceTransportPolicy is "relay", the google stun URL also no longer works, not just my STUN server.

And monitoring wireshark traffic, I can see STUN requests on the loopback traffic capture which shows 2 interesting things:

1. The STUN request is not going out to the internet.
2. I also notice a **username** attribute in the STUN request.

But according to the STUN spec, usernames are not possible with STUN, so how is the browser achieving that?

**Update 2: 21 Mar 2020**
I've discovered that my STUN response wasn't correct, it returned a binding indication response.
I've fixed it to return a binding success response.
But, it still doesn't work.
I managed to review the chrome logs, and it seems all my ICE candidates are being ignored and the following are the reasons I see in the logs:

1. Discarding candidate because it doesn't match filter.
2. AllocationSequence: Relay ports disabled, skipping.

So I think this narrows it down a bit more.
Maybe I need to enable certain features in Chrome?
Or what else could I be missing?

Comment: STUN server aside, Is your public server test url using SSL? I can't really answer your question but that popped into my mind when you say it works for `localhost` but not on the web. I once went deep down the network/NAT/STUN rabbit hole and it turned out to be that browsers require https for certain WebRTC things.

Comment: The website is on https on the web, but not on localhost. I looked into the UDP over SSL/TLS, but there doesn't seem to be anything native to .net for that really, so I am leaving it for now.
I've been looking at node.js open source projects mostly for code example and ideas and I can't recall seeing anything related to http/s actually. I'll look more, might actually be just the thing, you never know.

Comment: STUN server is not required if two peers are in LAN because webrtc library can find out the ip addresses by going through the network interfaces. What is not working when you host it on the public domain? STUN is needed for non-LAN use cases but that only wont solve the whole problem, TURN server is also needed.

Comment: When I specify a STUN URL when on public domain, the onicecandidate event never triggers, even if I use google's STUN url.  Why do you say I also need a TURN server??

Comment: Make sure you used the test tool using Firefox. I also get 701 when using chrome. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

Comment: I have gone through your above-mentioned issues. I am more willing to assist you in this matter, but I will suggest you, please visit my tutorial on Github. I hope that would help you a lot. Visit: [Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC) .

Comment: Thank you.
But i believe STUN only works on a local network. To have this work over the internet I think I'm supposed to implement an TURN or ICE server.